# Overriding dependencies in bower.json file

Tags: bower

I am trying to override the dependencies for one of the packages I am including in a polymer component, and can't seem to get it to work.

bower.json file looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
"polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.0.0",
"paper-material": "PolymerElements/paper-material#^1.0.0",
"paper-toolbar" : "PolymerElements/paper-toolbar#^1.0.0",
"paper-styles": "PolymerElements/paper-styles#^1.0.0",
"iron-icon": "polymerelements/iron-icon#^1.0.0",
"iron-icons": "polymerelements/iron-icons#^1.0.0"
},

"overrides": {
  "paper-styles": {
    "dependencies": {
     "iron-flex-layout": "PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout#^1.0.0",
     "font-roboto": "PolymerElements/font-roboto-local#^1.0.1",
     "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.0.0"
   }
 }
},
"devDependencies": {
  "iron-component-page": "PolymerElements/iron-component-page#^1.0.0",
  "web-component-tester": "*"
```

}

basically I am trying to replace the font-roboto package with the font-roboto-local package.    Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Unless I am interpreting the documentation incorrectly, this should work.

Answer (score 3):

Bower uses a flat dependency tree; so you don't need to change the dependencies of paper-styles via `overrides`, you can do it directly in your `bower.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "paper-styles": "PolymerElements/paper-styles#^1.0.0",
  "font-roboto": "PolymerElements/font-roboto-local#^1.0.0"
}
```

Edit: At first this worked for me, but then bower suddenly switch back to using `font-roboto`. This seems to be because `paper-styles` requires ^1.0.1, but `font-roboto-local` is only available in 1.0.0. This means that for bower satisfying the version is more important than *which package* to install.

I could fix this by setting the version to 1.0.0 without ^:

```
"dependencies": {
  "paper-styles": "PolymerElements/paper-styles#^1.0.0",
  "font-roboto": "PolymerElements/font-roboto-local#1.0.0"
},
"resolutions": {
  "font-roboto": "1.0.0"
}
```

The disadvantage is that you manually have to update the version now, but at least it works.

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to overrider the dependencies of a child,  what you have listed here will certainly work if I update the package directly, but for a child it does not.